# A message comes that a particular module does not exist and it really does

Tags: angular

I'm trying to run a new project and I get an error message: An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json' 
I checked the package.json and found that this module exists.
In all the ways I try to solve the problem it still remains.

I tried to do the command: npm cache clean --force  and I still have
 a screenshot for an error message

I would appreciate if anyone could help me

Comment: delete node modules and reinstall using npm i

Comment: Can you search for "@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json" any where in the repo. You might be trying to import {} from "@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json";